# Transform MVC to layered Architecture in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, architecture, soa, n-tier-architecture

I have a classic Spring Boot app, you can see the structure:
[image]

I am trying to modify it to have at the end a Layered Architecture.
The problem is that to isolate the layers we must to use APIs between layers,so I have no idea how to create API's for each Layer, maybe you can give some examples?
Here is the classic structure of Layered Arch.
[image]

And this is my structure.

[image]

Some codes from my app:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
…
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User theUser…){
    theUser.setPassword(value);
    userService.save(theUser);
}
…
}
```

...

```
@Service
@Component("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements Services<User> {
…
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(User theUser) {
   theUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(theUser.getPassword()));
   userDao.saveUser(theUser);

}
…
}
```

...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AnnonceRestController {
@GetMapping("/announce-all")
public List<Annonce> findAll() {
    return annonceService.findAll();
}


@PostMapping("/announce-create")
public Annonce addAnnonce(@RequestBody Annonce theAnnonce) {

    theAnnonce.setId(0);
    theAnnonce.setDate(null);
    annonceService.save(theAnnonce);

    return theAnnonce;
}
```

Comment: I think you have some definition problems here. First : what is a layered architecture for you ? N-Tier ? Hexagonal ? Clean Architecture, Onion Architecture ?

What do you call API ? Is it just about calling interfaces instead of implementations ? Or is it about REST apis ?

Comment: I would say the API between each of the layers in your diagram is the public classes and methods that have been exposed through classes or interfaces. Anything that shouldn't be exposed to other layers should be private or package private.